# what is the maximum value of a lucene score?

Tags: java, lucene

I am thinking about the default scoring function for which StandardAnalyzer has been used.

It seems the value is sometimes above 1.0.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There isn't really a maximum score.

When Lucene does it's scoring, it basically sums a set of scores together to give a total score.

For example:

> Suppose I search for `A OR B`. This query is broken into its constituent parts - `A` and `B`. Each part of this query is searched independently using a sub-scorer and given score for the relevant part of the query. If a document contains both `A` and `B`, the score will be a combination of scores from both sub-scorers.

Because there can be many sub-scorers, the total score can be greater than 1.

The score of a particular hit is absolute, meaning that it can only be used as a comparison to the highest score from the same search. Scores across different searches are not directly comparable.

If you really do need a value between 0 and 1, you can normalise each score based on the ratio of its value to the highest score from the search. This will give you the equivalent of a percentage score. These percentages still cannot be compared across searches though.

More info can be found [here](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ#Can_I_filter_by_score.3F) and [here](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/ScoresAsPercentages).

Answer (score 5):

The maximum value of score depends on the query being executed. To find out what is maximum score for a given query, you can request **score** field through **fl** parameter, it needs to be explicitly requested.

```
Ex Req: http://server:7983/solr/select/?q=term&fl=*,score
```

look for maxScore="xx.xxxx" in your response, and this will go above/below 1.0, depending on the query, results, relevance...

```
Ex: <result name="response" numFound="29" start="0" maxScore="2.1740298">
```

Whats important to remember the value of score itself does not offer much meaning, but when compare the relative score of a document to that of maxScore of the query it provides value. For instance if the score of a document#1 is 1.9 & that of a document#27 is 0.8, then document#1 is far superior match than document#27 when maxScore is "2.1740298".

The following affects scoring,

- Inverse Document Frequency
- Term Frequency
- Coordination Factor
- Field Length

besides this features like

- Index Time Boosting
- Query Time Boosting

will affect how a score is calculated. [SolrRelevancy](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ) offers some explanation. More detailed explanation can be found here [Lucene Similarity](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_5_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/Similarity.html) You can turn on debug option to see how score is computed,

```
http://server:7983/solr/select/?q=term&fl=*,score&debugQuery=on
```

**Ex:**
    2.1740298 = fieldWeight(text:"mmdci bldleg 02" in 210), product of:
    1.7320508 = tf(phraseFreq=3.0)
    13.388552 = idf(text: mmdci=812 bldleg=264 02=6220)
    0.09375 = fieldNorm(field=text, doc=210)

**For Lucene:**

Use **TopDocs.getMaxScore()**. Returns the max score of all matches, when doing default sort by relevance. If you are sorting by field other than relevance you need to set **doTrackScores(true)** & **doMaxScore(true)**.

Comment: +1. Thanks. Good explanation. I do not use solr, I use directly lucene , so I guess there is something similar to obtain the maxScore for a given query.

Comment: Sorry overlooked the fact that you were using **Lucene** without **Solr**. Edited my answer to include it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a page describing how scores are calculated in Lucene:

http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_0/scoring.html

Comment: Please read the FAQ and stop simply posting links as answers.